# My function to set margin is not working consistently

Tags: javascript, css

I am trying to set a div just under my header, which has a position of "fixed". I am using a function to find the "clientHeight" of the header, add a few pixels and set the "marginTop to the div. Every few times I load the page or reload the page, the image isn't always in the desired position. I am relatively new to using js to make a responsive site. Only started coding a couple of months ago.

I tried setting the div ("#page") to absolute and using the "top" style attribute. That really didn't work.
I tried using relative too but that was much the same as my initial attempt.

Also I have only tested this in Chrome and Firefox (Latest versions).

Works fine in this fiddle, but not when I run it in the actual browser.

Below is the function in question.

```
function bodyMarginTop () {
    const header = document.querySelector("header");
    const page = document.getElementById("page");

    page.style.marginTop = (header.clientHeight + 8) + "px";
}
```

https://jsfiddle.net/Cpt_Crooked/yf8xj3s0/2/

Expected result:

- I want the white div to appear 8pxs under the header no matter the view port width, how many times the page is loaded, or which browser is being used.

Actual result:

- Chrome: Page loads correctly roughly 70% of the time. Sometimes it appears 
  too high on the page sometimes too low.
- Firefox: Same as Chrome only much less consistent as it only loads correctly roughly 10% of the time.

Comment: PS, would be nice you used `*{margin:0;padding:0;box-sizing:border-box;}` or browse the internet for CSS resets - to get a clue

Comment: @RokoC.Buljan Deleted my comment as I missed the "Works fine in this fiddle, but not when I run it in the actual browser." part :) (I was testing on the fiddle)

Comment: Also, I think you're using JS in vain. All the above can be done using CSS only... Your page is strange, and by using JS instead of CSS to control positions you'll make it additionally jumpy and flashy, since JS triggers once the elements are flowed and painted.

Comment: @RokoC.Buljan Thanks so much for the response. I only started coding 4 months ago and trying to teach myself. I think I might have gone through things a little too quickly and missed a few things. The reason I used JS, is so that regardless of the device's width, and whether the window is resized, the div would remain a set distance from the header (8px in this case.) I have no idea how I would manage that with just CSS.

Comment: Also I did add a cdn link to normalize. That would take care of all the default margins and padding, I assume?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Make sure the function is called after all elements are loaded on the page by adding a  `load` event to the `window` object like so:

```
window.addEventListener("load", bodyMarginTop);
```

Comment: This is great  as it loads all content before the function is run. Thanks @Sheedo.

Answer (score 0):

Load the DOM before running JS on the elements.

```
document.onreadystatechange = function () {
  if (document.readyState === 'interactive') {
    bodyMarginTop();
  }
}
```

Comment: Thank you @Rishabh. With my limited experience, I will definitely use this if I need to do more than one thing on the loading of the page. One thing I will change though is the readystate from "interactive" to "complete".

Comment: If you use 'complete' or 'load' then the function will wait for all the resources to load first including images and external scripts. This won't provide a very good user experience because you may find a screen flicker/readjustment after loading of resources. Ideal way is to use 'interactive' because DOM loading time will be very less compared to all the resources.

Comment: I will definitely keep that in mind. Seems I have a fair amount of reading to do ;)